# how make statement if in xcode to change value

Tags: xcode, if-statement, swiftui

```
@State var password: String = ""
@State var passwordConfirm: String = ""
@State private var buttonDisabled = true


  if password == passwordConfirm{
                       self.buttonDisabled = false
                   }else{
                       self.buttonDisabled = true
                   }
```

i want change value buttonDisabled with condition if,when password and passwordConfirm same, pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by disabling the button when `password == passwordConfirm`.

I created two `TextFields` to demonstrate what you want but would suggest you using `SecureField` for passwords.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var passwordConfirm: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Password", text: $password)
            TextField("Confirm password", text: $passwordConfirm)

            Button(action: {
                print(self.password == self.passwordConfirm)
            }) {
                Text("Create Account")
            }.disabled(password == passwordConfirm)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @sfung3,
but i want know, Is it possible use statement to change value in xcode?
in case if in the future I need it